# Dart : How to create a stream that aggregates events from another stream?

Tags: dart, stream, dart-async

What is the best way to create a stream that needs to aggregate multiple events from another Stream ?

My goal is to create a stream that aggregates events from another stream until it has enough events to build a message. In my case I am reading data from the Socket stream so a message may be distributed across different events and an event may contain data for various messages, hence I can't just apply a map operation over each element.

It seems the correct would way would be to use a Stream Transformer yet I am having trouble finding information on how to implement it correctly and without too much boilerplate code.

I came up with a solution after reading about how to create streams but I am not sure if this is acceptable nor the best way to do it.

Here's my solution example:

```
Stream<String> joinWordsIfStartWithC(Stream<String> a) async* {
  var prevWord= '';
  await for (var i in a) {
    prevWord += i;
    if(i.startsWith('C')){
      yield prevWord;
      prevWord = '';
    }
  }
}

Stream<String> periodicStream(Duration interval) async* {
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(interval);
    yield 'C';
    yield 'A';
    yield 'B';
    yield 'C';
    yield 'C';
    yield 'B';
    yield 'C';
  }
}

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var intStream = periodicStream(Duration(seconds: 2));

  var sStream = joinWordsIfStartWithC(intStream);

  sStream.listen((s) => print(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will say your solution seems to be fine but if you want to make a stream transformer it is rather easy by extending from [`StreamTransformerBase`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/StreamTransformerBase-class.html):

```
import 'dart:async';

class JoinWordsIfStartWithCTransformer extends StreamTransformerBase<String, String> {
  Stream<String> bind(Stream<String> a) async* {
    var prevWord = '';
    await for (var i in a) {
      prevWord += i;
      if (i.startsWith('C')) {
        yield prevWord;
        prevWord = '';
      }
    }
  }
}

Stream<String> periodicStream(Duration interval) async* {
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(interval);
    yield 'C';
    yield 'A';
    yield 'B';
    yield 'C';
    yield 'C';
    yield 'B';
    yield 'C';
  }
}

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var intStream = periodicStream(Duration(seconds: 2));

  var sStream = intStream.transform(JoinWordsIfStartWithCTransformer());

  sStream.listen((s) => print(s));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your example while simple helped me finally understand what I was supposed to do in the bind method. I did not realise I could just return the stream.